# can anybody help me out to get type of input type in php

Tags: php

Can anybody help me out   to get the type of input type in php.
For example

```
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<input type="text" name="a" /><br />
<input type="text" name="b" /><Br />
<input type="file" name="c" /><Br />
<input type="text" name="d" /><Br />
<input type="file" name="e" br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Result Should be:
text,
text,
file,
text,
file,
submit

i m creating a class that would be validate every field by its type,so i need to know how to get type of input type in PHP.For Example if input type is text then this class would validate field like numeric or alhpanumeric,checkempty or many types of filtration and if the input type is rest or submit,then it would goes on ignore and if the input type is file,then it will be validate in other way.I hope information is clear now,and i will be very happy if anybody can help me out

Comment: That’s not possible in PHP with the HTML intact.

Comment: Why do you want to do that. What are you trying to accomplish? There might be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) hidden in here.

Comment: You cab set input names like `text[a]`, `text[b]`, for example, but better explain why do you need this.

Comment: It would be valuable if you clarify with a bit more information on why you want to achieve this, it might help us work out how to achieve this.

Comment: i m creating a class that would be validate every field by its type,so i need to know how to get type of input type in PHP.For Example if input type is text then this class would validate field   like numeric or alhpanumeric,checkempty or many types of filtration and if the input type is rest or submit,then it would goes on ignore and if the input type is file,then it will be validate in other way.I hope information is clear now,and i will be very happy if anybody can help me out.

Answer (score 2):

That is not possible. Submitting a `form` will only send the `name` of a field with the corresponding value in either a get or a post request to a specified page. There is no way for php to detect what the type of field was where the data came from.

Answer (score 1):

It cannot be done in PHP or any other language because the browser does not send the input type to the server. Everything always is a string, or to be more precise: The value either supplied by the user or the original HTML value attribute.